# Need to write a stored procedure to collate strings into a single string for matched IDs and write results to new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

To illustrate, imagine I have a table containing multiple authors with each row a unique author and book title pair. So, if any author had written 12 books this would take up 12 rows. There are as many rows as books by all the authors.

From this I want to create a new table with two fields; one row per author name with a second field a concatenated (or comma delimited or whichever) list of all their respective books.

So far I've wanted to step through a recordset in VB which seems a bit clumsy and clunky and it would much better sit as a stored procedure to be called from code.

I imagine a mechanism whereby I step through and store the author name in a variable and at the same time store the book title in another. After the first iteration if the author hasn't changed then the next book title is added to the variable containing the book titles and this continues with the book list variable growing. When the author changes the previous author and the current string containing the book titles so far are added to the new table, the book list variable is then reset to blank and the author variable changed and we continue iterating.

Problem is I'm not that familiar with raw SQL and whilst I may be able to hack something together suspect I might be missing a trick here and a clean way of doing this.

Comment: Can you please your input/ expected output ?

Comment: Hint:  `STRING_AGG()`.

Comment: _"second field a concatenetaed (or comma delimited or whichever) list of all their repsective books."_ bad idea, don't do that.

Comment: What if you have a book title like `'My dear, don''t do that.'`? This will lead to wrong results as it will be counted to 2 books. And lead to use a string splitter.

Comment: String_agg() would be great and I'm not familiar with it althouhg this in on an old version. When we upgrade I'll make a note of this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible route is to use `for xml path` to list them. This also encapsulates each book in double quotation marks in case a comma is in the book title:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#books') is not null
    drop table #books

create table #books (author varchar(100), book varchar(100))

insert into #books (author,book)
values ('Shakespeare','Hamlet')
,('Shakespeare','Winter''s Tale')
,('Milton','Paradise Lost')
,('Milton','Lycidas')

select * from #books


select
author,
    stuff((
        select 
        ', ' + quotename(b.book,'"')
        from #books b
        where b.author = #books.author
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as book_list
from #books
group by author
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. String_Agg() I guess would have worked were I running a later version but this did the trick. I did suspect there'd be a cleaner way to do it than stepping through a recordset, much appreciated cheers

Comment: You're welcome - please could you mark as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, been away - should be tagged now, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

The most recent versions of SQL Server support `string_agg()`:

```
select author, string_agg(book, ',')
from author_books ab
group by author;
```

Comment: Imagine if there is a book title like `'My dear, don''t do that.'`. What would be the results when you try to get the books?

Comment: @Sami It would be fine, it's already in the string and would just be aggregated like all the rest.

Comment: @Sami also if you're worried about that you could introduce a text delimiter with `quotename` ie. `select author, string_agg(quotename(book,''''),',') from #books group by author`

Comment: @TJB It's ok? As it is it will give the wrong [results](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=539c3b0f10cf41515abcc121ad7eb583) and that in the first place breaks the [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) rules.

Comment: @Sami "it's ok" was from a perspective of 'the function will work with it'.  But otherwise see my `quotename` suggestion. Also he's not looking to `string_split`, so answers should be focused around aggregation.

Comment: This is great thanks, although not available on current version - v useful for future ref. For separation I'll use another delimiter anyway, probably a line break or something.